# How to use observe in observable objects in MobX

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, observable, mobx

It's the first time I'm in contact in MobX and in this project I have a pretty simple task, `data` is and `@observable` and I have a graphql subscription, and I need to `observe` for a specific change in the data. I have this atm:

```
 @persist("object") @observable public data: IPlayer | null = null;

@action public async syncData(now = Date.now()) {
    sub.subscribe(res => {
      if (res?.data?.player) {
        this.data = res?.data?.player;
        console.log(`this.data: ${JSON.stringify(this.data, null, 2)}`);

      observe(this.data, "ipfs", () => {
        console.log("NEW IPFS CONFIG");
      })
      }
    });
  }
```

The subscription works fine and `this.data` updates the values however `this.data.ipfs` is a really big nested object and if I change something inside of it it does not trigger the `observe`

Answer (score 0):

From [mobx](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observe.html) documentation:

`observe(user.name, listener)` is fundamentally different from `observe(user, "name", listener)`. The first observes the current `value` inside `user.name` (which might not be an observable at all), the latter observes the `name` property of `user`.

So the solution is to change the way you observe this object

```
observe(this.data.ipfs, () => {
   console.log("NEW IPFS CONFIG");
})
```

**Important: Every time you update the value of `ipfs`, you should add new observation as below**

Comment: Thx I'll try it when pick on this problem again